# Convert rule in string format to arules in R

Tags: r, string, type-conversion, arules

I have a couple of Apriori rules in string format like: 
(A,B) => (C) ,Support=0.1 ,Confidence=0.0

Is it possible to convert them into the same format returned by apriori function in arulesViz library, i.e a >rules object?

Format has this aspect:

```
   lhs                rhs         support     confidence
```

[1]   {A B}            => {C}          0.1          0.0

PS:I cannot directly use apriori function from R since I am using a modified version of it.

Thank you
Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are always of a similar format then the following should work.

```
a <- rep('(A,B) => (C) ,Support=0.1 ,Confidence=0.0',6)

b  <- matrix(unlist(strsplit(a,' ,')),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)

b[,1] <- gsub('[(]','{',b[,1])
b[,1] <- gsub('[)]','}',b[,1])
b[,1] <- gsub(',',' ',b[,1])
b[,2:3] <- gsub('^.*=','',b[,2:3])
paste(b[,1],b[,2],b[,3])
```

I can't think of any concise way to do it but split the strings up and deal with sub-strings.